# Runtime Error 13 on cell not in Range

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I am working on a simple spreadsheet that changes characters when you click on the cell, then counts the cells that are of a certain character.  I have set the range to only look at certain cells (A3:A27, B3:B27) but anytime I click on row 1 I get a

> Runtime Error 13.  This row is outside of the selected Range.

Here is my code.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim rng As Range

Set rng = Range("A3:A27,B3:B27")
        If Target.Value = Chr(254) Then
            Target.Value = Chr(168)
            Cancel = True
        ElseIf Target.Value = Chr(168) Then
            Target.Value = Chr(254)
            Cancel = True
        End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Update:  I get the runtime error 13 anytime multiple cells are selected anywhere in the spreadsheet, whether inside or outside of the set range.  The reason I noticed it with row 1 is because it has several merged cells.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try looping through the cells in `Target`

Comment: @user1025198,, nothing wrong with the code, I've tried the Code and it's working without any error for me!! The `Run-time Error 13` occurs when you attempt to run VBA code that contains data types that are not matched correctly and in your case it doesn't applies!!